# Deployment Automatization for docker builds, kubernetes deploys and secret injection

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I've written a small script that automates the tasks I previously did manually for deploying onto our kubernetes clusters and I am quite happy with the results I have, but I do think that what my approach was (building a command and executing it at the end) could probably be improved.

Especially the `fn_magic` part is something I dont know could be done better.

```bsh
team="webdev"
project="sick-project"
registry="myfancyregistry"
tagPrefix="$registry/$team/$project"
namespace="webdev-dev"
kubectl="kubectl -n=$namespace"

declare -A NAME_TO_TAGS
declare COMMANDBUILDER
declare -A REPLACEMENTS

# Colors :)
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
BLUE='\033[0;34m'
CYAN='\033[0;36m'
YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

function setReplacements() {
  while IFS= read -r line
  do
    [ -z "$line" ] && continue
    key=${line%%=*}
    value=${line#*=}
    REPLACEMENTS[$key]=$value
  done < "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/secrets"
}

function buildAndPush() {
  function fn_magic() {
    local dockerfile=$1
    local name=$2
    local context=$3
    local tag=$(tar cf - --exclude='node_modules' $context | sha1sum | grep -o "\w*")
    NAME_TO_TAGS["$name"]="$tag"
    local output=$(docker images $tagPrefix/$project-$name:$tag | awk '{print $2}' | sed 1,1d)
    printf "SHA1 for ${CYAN}$name${NC} is ${YELLOW}$tag${NC}.\n"
    if [[ "$output" ]]; then
      printf "Skipping building ${CYAN}$name${NC} because image already exists locally.\n"
      COMMANDBUILDER="$COMMANDBUILDER && printf \"Pushing ${CYAN}$name${NC}.\n\" && docker push $tagPrefix/$project-$name:$tag"
      return
    fi
    COMMANDBUILDER="$COMMANDBUILDER && printf \"Building ${CYAN}$name${NC}.\n\" && docker build -f dockerfiles/$dockerfile.dockerfile -t $tagPrefix/$project-$name:$tag $context"
    COMMANDBUILDER="$COMMANDBUILDER && printf \"Pushing ${CYAN}$name${NC}.\n\" && docker push $tagPrefix/$project-$name:$tag"
    return
  }
  local calls=(
    "fn_magic ReactNginx frontend ./frontend"
    "fn_magic DockerfileNode backend ./backend"
  )

  for call in "${calls[@]}"; do 
    eval $call
  done
}

function deploy() {
  local deployName="$1"
  local tag="$2"

  local filter=""
  REPLACEMENTS[TAG]="$tag"
  for key in "${!REPLACEMENTS[@]}"; do
    local REPLACE=$(echo ${REPLACEMENTS[$key]} | sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g; s/\//\\\//g; s/&/\\\&/g')
    filter="$filter | sed \"s/{{$key}}/$REPLACE/g\""
  done

  COMMANDBUILDER="$COMMANDBUILDER && cat "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/$deployName.yaml" $filter | $kubectl apply -f -"
}

setReplacements
buildAndPush
for name in "${!NAME_TO_TAGS[@]}"; do 
  deploy $name ${NAME_TO_TAGS[$name]}
done
COMMANDBUILDER="echo $COMMANDBUILDER"
eval "$COMMANDBUILDER"
```

Comment: So that we can clearly understand what this code is intended to accomplish, could you include some example inputs and results?

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions in rough order of decreasing importance:

- `eval` is evil, and I'm pretty sure you can completely avoid it in your script. Other than a massive gain in sanity, all that `sed` stuff to escape strings is not going to be necessary if you instead just use plain shell.
- Naming is really important, and comments are a good way to detect things which should be renamed.
- `set -o errexit -o nounset -o pipefail` would be very handy in this script. Just make sure you're aware of the [caveats](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) (that page is needlessly snarky but has some useful bits, and that site is fantastic).
- A simple array is the best way to [build a command](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). I would thoroughly recommend *not* building complex commands using a shell script. Instead, run each command as soon as you have all the pieces. Bundling up commands to run isn't going to make things faster; in most cases it'll make things significantly slower by making >50% of the code about *building* the command rather than just running it.
- Nested functions aren't. There are no closures in Bash, so defining a function within another function just makes it harder to read.
- In Bash the convention is that uppercase names are reserved for *`export`ed* variables.
- Single use variables can often be inlined without loss of clarity.
- `printf` is meant to be used with format strings for readability. So

  ```
  printf "SHA1 for ${cyan}$name${end_format} is ${yellow}$tag${end_format}.\n"
  ```

  would normally be written as

  ```
  printf "SHA1 for %s is %s.\n" "${cyan}${name}${end_format}" "${yellow}${tag}${end_format}"
  ```
- `local` is considered a *command* for exit code purposes, which means that `local foo=[variable or command substitution]` only gets the exit code of `local`, *not* of the variable or command substitution. So if you start using `nounset` and the like you should declare variables local *before* assigning them separately:

  ```
  deploy() {
      local deploy_name tag
      deploy_name="$1"
      tag="$2"
      …
  }
  ```
- [`shellcheck`](https://www.shellcheck.net/) can give you more tips.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. An array definitely makes more sense to build a command.

However I dont quite understand the `local` part. All the other best practices make sense, especially shellcheck is really helpful but as far as I understood, `local` is used to have a variable not in the global scope or did I misunderstand that?

Comment: I've added an example to clarify how to use `local`.

Comment: Ahhh, wow that's really good to know. Thanks for the inconvenience in helping me out :)

Comment: No worries, I wouldn't be doing this unless I got something out of it as well - code reading and review training, writing training, and the pleasure of helping. And it often forces me to rethink what I consider best practices and articulate *why* I think they are preferable to the alternatives.